# Error: Unknown column 'Date' in 'field list'

Tags: php, javascript, html, xampp

I am working on a blood bank data base but i am repeatedly getting a Error:          Unknown column 'Date' in 'field list'.there is no spelling error in either php or mysql so here is my php code

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bloodbank");
    // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

   $sql="INSERT INTO users       (First,Last,Date,Email,Contact,Bloodgroup,Gender,address,City,username,password)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[first]','$_POST[last]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[contact]','$_POST[bg]',
'$_POST[sex]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?></code>
```

Comment: What is the table structure?

Comment: What's the structure of your users table? Does it have a field called `date`?

Comment: most likely you do not have `Date` column in the `users` table

Comment: also since `date` is a keyword you should escape it like `\`Date\``

Comment: @Stephan - is date a reserved word in MySQL? I can't see it on the list: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html
(Oh, never mind - I was looking in the wrong place. I need more coffee)

Comment: @andrewsi it is a type in mysql, so it should be escaped

Comment: @JurijsNesterovs - so I noticed; I was looking in the list of reserved words, and didn't see the section underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic explanation would be that Your query does not matches with your table structure

```
INSERT INTO users(First,Last,Date
                             ^ // Right here you are using it
```

Check your table structure using tools like phpMyAdmin and if the field does exist, **Date** is a reserved word so that might be creating the problem.

Comment: @manju, Can you show me your table structure, and have you changed the code to after changing the column name?

Comment: thanks man just saw i declared column name as dob ,now everything is fine.Another doubt i am using xampp,should i store all the html,php files in htdocs folder and should i store phpmyadmin folder inside htdocs?

Comment: Thanks everyone changed the column name and it worked,thanks.